# Submit dynamical form using JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I´m not really sure I can do this, but it's worth the try.

I have a table with at least 10 items coming from a Mysql database. They are items for which you can bid. The idea is that every row (therefore, every item) has a button that can be clicked to enter the bid. This button opens a popup with a text field to enter the bid and a button to submit the form.

In order to identify the item the user is bidding for, I need its id, as well as the amount bid. The amount is really easy to get, but I´m struggling a lot with the item id.

Here is what I have:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".show").click(function() {
   $("#popup").show();
      var $id = document.getElementsByClassName('show')[0].value;
      console.log($id);
      $("#jugador").val($id);
 });

 $("#close, #submit").click(function() {
   $("#popup").hide();
 });
});
```

```css
#popup {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
  padding: 10px;
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  background: #ccc;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #000;
  z-index: 5;
  opacity: 0.4;
}
```

```html
<td><button class="show" id="bid" value="<?php echo $row2["id"];?>"><img src="pictures/bidIcon.png" width="30" height="30"></button></td>

/*Popup*/

<div id="popup" style="display: none;">
 <div class="overlay"></div>
  <div class="content">
    <header>
     <div id="close">✖</div>
    </header>
    <form name="form1" method="post" action="bid.php">
     <fieldset>
      <label for="bid">Bid:</label>
      <input type="text" name="bidAmount" id="bidAmount" size="8" />
      <input type="hidden" name="item" id="item" />
      <input type="submit" tabindex="-1" style="position:absolute; top:-1000px">
    </fieldset>
    <footer>
    <button type="button" id="submit">Bid Now</button>
    </footer>
   </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

I´ve been trying for a while with no luck. I will always get the item id for the first element no matter in which button I click.

Is it feasible what I want? Is this the correct approach? Should I use a different one?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Do you have multiple bid buttons? You are always selecting the first element with a class, don't you want the one inside the button that was clicked?

Comment: generate dynmic ids and then pass in button like <button id="dynamicid by php"onsubmit="func(this.id)" >

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just change this line:

```
var $id = document.getElementsByClassName('show')[0].value;
```

To this:

```
var $id = $(this).val();
```

The problem is that with `document.getElementsByClassName('show')[0].value` you are querying the first occurrence of the `.show` button. With `$(this)` instead you will be accessing the current clicked button.

JQuery binds the events to the target where you attach the event, so `this` will always be a reference to the target of the event. Using `$(this)` will create a jQuery object of the target element permitting to apply jQuery functions to the element.

As a side note, you shouldn’t duplicate the elements ids. Every id must be unique in the html document, so it will be a good practice to make that id different for each button.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I don't even know what to say. I'm very very amateur with JQuery/Javascript and I was getting crazy...Thank you so much muecas.

Comment: @saysmus no problem. I’m glad I could help you.

Answer (score 1):

To access the current div element's Id you can use the (**`$this`**), which refers to the current javascript object.

```js
$("div").click(function(){
 alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="1">Num 1</div>
<div id="2">Num 2</div>
<div id="3">Num 3</div>
<div id="4">Num 4</div>
```

Here in this example, i have created div's which when clicked return's the id of that div.

Answer (score 1):

When you do it like this `var $id = document.getElementsByClassName('show')[0].value;` it will always take the first element having `class="show"`.
Which will contain the first item hence always gives the `id` of first item.
So instead of doing it like that you can do it like this:

```
var $id = $(this).val();
```

This will select the current item on which user has clicked so will give the id of that item.